# JSch: ByteArrayInputStream: How to check the terminal result

Tags: java, jsch

I will use Jsch to ssh to another server
And check if the path exist

But I found that the `baos.toString()`
will print out all the result on terminal  :

```
test -d /root/bin/python || echo python not found
test -d /root/bin/java || echo java not found
test -d Desktop || echo java not found
[root@s1 ~]# test -d /root/bin/python || echo python not found
[root@s1 ~]# test -d /root/bin/java || echo java not found
```

So It will always return false :

```
if (baos.toString().contains("not found")){
                 return false;
             }
```

Code:

```
    String command = null;           
    command = String.format("test -d %s || echo python not found\n"
        + "test -d %s || echo java not found\n",python,java);       
    try{ 
       JSch jsch = new JSch();
       jsch.addIdentity("/Users/.ssh/id_rsa");  

       Session session = jsch.getSession("root", IP, 22);
       session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
       session.connect(10*1000);
       Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
       InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(command.getBytes());
       ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        channel.setInputStream(is);
        channel.setOutputStream(baos);
        channel.connect(15 * 1000);
        Thread.sleep(3*1000);
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
        logger.debug(baos.toString());
        if (baos.toString().contains("not found")){
             return false;
         }
    }catch (DataAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }      
    return true;
```

Please help me

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use the [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class?

Comment: @RedRoboHood That's seriously outdated. [`Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) would be a better option.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Wow, I had no idea that existed... I wish I had learned about that earlier.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is the expected behavior? What is it supposed to do that it is not doing?

Comment: But your edit did not answer my question. **What is it supposed to do**?

Comment: if it detect the program didn't installed the packages , return false.

Comment: @user2492364 What is the string that is printed in the logger.debug() call? This should give you an idea on the contents of the returned byte array

Comment: this : 
test -d /root/bin/python || echo python not found
test -d /root/bin/java || echo java not found
test -d Desktop || echo java not found
[root@s1 ~]# test -d /root/bin/python || echo python not found
[root@s1 ~]# test -d /root/bin/java || echo java not found

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, Jsch echoes the input in much the same way a real ssh session does. You can work around this problem by changing the string that you echo.

For example, instead of

```
echo java not found
```

Use

```
echo not found java
```

Why? Because then the words "not found" would be the first on the line, as opposed to the echoed input lines. So you can now slightly change your match:

```
 if (baos.toString().contains("\nnot found")){
     return false;
 }
```

Note the `\n` character. If the "not found" comes at the beginning of a line in the output (after a newline), then it will be found and `false` will be returned. If it doesn't come at the beginning of a line, it will not be found.

You might want to look at the [jcabi-ssh library](http://ssh.jcabi.com/) which wraps around jsch, and is a lot easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `java.io.File` class. Something like the function below should help:

```
import java.io.File;
private boolean doesFileExist(String fileName)
{
   File f = new File(fileName);
   return f.exists();
}
```

Your file name in this case would be `/root/workspace/file1` or `/root/workspace/file2`

Comment: The `File` class shouldn't be used in this day and age. [`Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) is preferred.

Comment: But I have to ssh to another server,baos is linux messages